# How to get date between two dates having in same column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table called holiday_master, in which there have column below

```
 | Id | Title  |       Date              |
 |:---|:-------|:------------------------|
 | 1  | Xmas   | 12-25-2021 - 12-30-2021 |
 | 2  | Diwali | 11-30-2021 - 12-02-2021 |
```

Let suppose I have current date 2021-12-27, Which occurs in first row, I want to get that record, Thanks in advance :)

Comment: ```... WHERE @specific_date BETWEEN CAST(LEFT(`Date`,10) AS DATE) AND CAST(RIGHT(`Date`,10) AS DATE)```. But I recommend to normalize your data.

Answer (score 2):

Bad database design leads to lots of issues. Your database is not usable. `Date` should be either timestamp or date format and be split to two columns: `start_date` and `end_date`

Then you can do

```sql
SELECT * FROM holiday_master WHERE start_date < :date AND end_date > :date
```